# 13.04: update-initramfs works but mkinitramfs fails from APT

Tags: apt, 13.04, initramfs

I'm experiencing a strange thing, I've freshly upgraded from 12.10 to 13.04, Everything is fine except that it can't build the initrd image automatically, it fails and prints out the mkinitramfs's *Usage* output.

I tried to debug the "mkinitramfs" script and it appears the $outfile variable is never set.
However, I'm able to produce the ramdisk manually like follow: *update-initramfs -c -u 3.0.8-23-generic*

I tried most of the stuff seen on the net: purge, reinstall but no help but nothing, and I can't use linux-image is marked as "broken" but the kernel exists in /boot.

Comment: I intented to but the dialog window you get by clicking on "answer your question" is not clear. BTW, it was not necessary to remove my update msg, I don't want to retype it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it, it seems that the kernel postinstall scripts is not compatible with my version of mkinitramfs (**initramfs-tools 0.103ubuntu0.7**).
In the linux-image postinstall script file, the call lacks of a parameter:
at line 837:

```
my $ret = system("$ramdisk " . ($upgrading ? "-u" : "-c") . " -k " . $version . " >&2");
```

should be  (Note the **-o** parameter before the **$version** variable.)

```
my $ret = system("$ramdisk " . ($upgrading ? "-u" : "-c") . " -k " . " -o " . $version . " >&2");
```

And it works! I was always bypassing this issue with a manual update-initramfs but I didn't like the fact that each time I used apt-get, dpkg status kept printing this error which fortunately was not blocking, then I had some spare time tonight and decided to put these on this annoying stuff and it pays off! =)

Unfortunately, it doesn't explain why an how I got this issue after an  distro-upgrade of my Ubuntu server using the official repositories. :/